# Vue: apply css class if product is in cart

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to make a shopping cart with laravel + vue, the main issue here is on vue's part.

In my  cart component you can add/remove products with a simple click, if a product is added to the cart I want to apply a css to the product card.

I created a computed property for this and added a class binding to the product card node but I'm getting the following error:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.isAlreadyAdded is not a function"

found in

---> <PRODUCTlchoice1> at resources/js/components/products/PRODUCTchoice1.vue
```

Here is my component:

```
<template>
<div style="width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-direction:column;">
        <div style="width:100%; height:auto; display:flex; flex-wrap:wrap; padding:10px;">
            <div :class="{ 'selected_product' : isAlreadyAdded(product.id) }" class="product" v-for="product in productcategory.products" :key="product.id" @click.self="selectProduct(product, $event)" style="width:31%; height:60px; border:0px solid black; background-color:rgb(235,235,235); margin:10px 10px; display:flex; align-items:center; padding:0px 5px 0px 20px; cursor:pointer;">
                <span style="font-size:20px; color:rgba(0,0,0,0.9);">{{ product.title }}</span>
                <div class="add_button" style="width:40px; height:40px; border-radius:2px; display:flex; align-items:center; justify-content:center; margin:0px 0px 0px auto; background-color:rgb(135, 229, 81);">
                    <i class="fa fa-plus" style="font-size:25px; color:white;"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
<!--SCRIPTS-->
<script>
import { mapState, mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';
export default {
name: 'PRODUCTlchoice1',


computed: {
    isAlreadyAdded: function(productId){
        return this.cartItem.find( cartItem => cartItem.id == productId);
    }

},


data() {
    return {
        cartItem: [],
        cartItems: [],
    }
},


props: {
    productcategories: { required:true }
},


mounted() {
    console.log(this.$options.name+' component successfully mounted');
},


methods:{

    selectProduct: function( product, event){

       //add or remove product logic

    },


}


};
</script>
<!--STYLES-->
<style scoped>
.product:hover{background-color:rgb(135, 229, 81) !important;}
.selected_product{background-color:var(--web_primary_color) !important; color:white; border:2px solid rgb(56,56,56);}
</style>
```

What's wrong with my code? should I use a computed property (this are reactive afaik?), I know I could capture the clicked event target and apply a class with css but I was adviced not to do this.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that, as the error suggests, your computed property `isAlreadyAdded` is not a function.

> But it is!

Well, you define computed properties as functions, that's true. But you must use them as **properties**.

Now, you can't do that because your `isAlreadyAdded` needs the `product` parameter. The `product` comes for an `v-for` directive, so you cannot reference this in the computed property itself (should `product` be a prop, you could). So you have two alternatives:

1. #### Just use a method

This is the simpler one. It is less performant than a computed property but it just works, and it is really difficult for anyone of your users to ever note the performance cost, I would swear.

2. #### Create a new component rendered for every product

If instead of rendering a `<div>` for every product you would render another Vue component, let's say `<my-product>`, and pass the `product` as a prop, you could use a computed property in that component, since now the `product` would be a prop, hence accessible by the computed property.

Beware!

Since the logic of such computation still needs the `cartItem` from the parent, this maybe is not the way to go. Things will be more complex than it seems.

Adding an extra component to handle the products may be nice, but in this case I would calculate wether they are added to the cart or not just with a Vue method in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

`isAlreadyAdded` is actually not a computed property in your use-case. It's a method and should be moved to the `methods` part of the component.

Referencing the `isAlreadyAdded` method in your class property binding makes it reactive on the result of that method.